# Why is pin protection needed?

Tags: microcontroller, power, heat, input, pins

I have read [this article about protecting input pins](http://www.digikey.com/en-US/articles/techzone/2012/apr/protecting-inputs-in-digital-electronics).

One thing is still unclear to me — why is the protection needed at all with such a high resistance on the input pin inside of the microcontroller? The current would be really small and the heat dissipation will be little as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Electrons are not only useful as carriers of electricity.  They are also responsible for binding atoms together in useful configurations.  Some materials have large numbers of "loose" electrons which can move around relatively freely without particularly affecting the material through which they are flowing.  Some other materials don't; given enough voltage, the electrons locked into the latter materials' structures can be knocked loose, but the act of knocking the electrons loose may permanently alter the structures in question.  A small amount of damage, concentrated in one place, can make a chip useless, and--in the absence of protection--it wouldn't take much energy to cause such damage.  The purpose of protection circuitry is to absorb energy over a much wider area, thus increasing the amount of energy that would need to be applied to cause damage.

Comment: Is the material you are talking about is the gate oxide layer in our case?

Answer (score 4):

The high voltage will destroy the gate oxide of the MOS transistors connected to an input pin. The real threat is from static electricity that builds up during handling and assembly of circuit boards.

Comment: But I thought it's heat dissipation that destroys components inside of ICs, which would be I*V. In this case considering a 10M Ohm resistor near the input pin, the current will be really low. So what does destroy the transistor exactly? I guess in the case of a static discharge the power will be high enough to destroy components, but what about just slightly higher voltage than expected? With protection diodes there would be a lot of current flowing through them since the 10M ohm resistor is placed after them. But what would be if they were not used?

Comment: ICs have built-in ESD protection structures.  Sometimes these are as simple as a Schottky diode clamp from the pin to ground and VCC.  In that case, a slightly higher than normal voltage could damage the ESD structure if there's enough current capability behind it.  Otherwise, a static charge buildup would have to have enough energy to overcome the ESD clamp and damage it, or the components it is protecting.  Unprotected MOS gates are extremely sensitive to ESD damage- The weakest part of the gate breaks down and a hole forms in the oxide.

Comment: What's the most common resistance and maximum voltage these MOS transistors near input pins usually have and can handle?

Comment: The resistance is very high (many GOhm), basically it behaves like a small capacitor. The voltage is in the tens of volts, which is very little w.r.t. static electricity. I.e. without protection diodes it would require a lot of ESD precautions not to kill it.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, the protection is primarily from [ESD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_discharge), which is usually more of an issue before the component is fitted to the PCB, although stray voltages finding their way in to (badly designed) equipment can also cause damage. ESD damage can happen without being noticed, and the component may fail days, weeks, months later.

Some designers, either being very brave or by knowing *very* well (probably in consultation with the device manufacturer) what they can get away with, will rely on the internal protection / current limiting features to save on adding external components (automotive designs do this sort of thing) but you really never should.

Edited to add, there's some good info on pin protection & abuse of it [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/106849/using-single-resistor-to-receive-5v-signal-on-the-3-3v-rated-pin).

Answer (score 1):

That article is talking about protecting against voltage spikes when using long wires to connect to an input pin.  It is the voltage, not the current, that could damage the pins.

If you are using short wires, or traces, you wouldn't need to worry about this.  But, if your wires are very long (multiple yards/meters), then the inductance of the wires can cause the spikes...

Good luck!

Comment: Could you please elaborate how voltage exactly damages components?

Comment: @EGDima There are multiple mechanisms where voltage can cause damage. The one you're most familiar with is that higher voltage can cause higher current, which may cause heat damage. Another mechanism is when the voltage breaks though an insulating or semi-conducting material, causing conductive paths... In the case of a transistor, this can cause them to "fail closed", because they always conduct...

Answer (score 0):

Because any electrical overstress is overstressing the component.

[Here's another short article](http://www.cypress.com/?docID=20619) (with pictures!) that talks about different kinds of electrical overstress.

I quickly skimmed that digikey article and it looks amazing. This is great advice to live by.

Comment: Did you mean to include a link?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think of it as there being a resistor ahead of the input circuit, thus protecting it.  Think of the resistor as being *part* of the input circuit.  The resistance is between two sensitive parts of the input, and ohm's law tells you how the voltage will behave.  Put a mere 10 microamps through a 1 megohm resistor and E=I/R tells you that you've got 10 volts.  This already would make a 3.3 volt input very unhappy.

It's not a real resistor in there, but for simplicity and for modeling purposes, it's good enough for illustration.